# Sending Too much messages programmatically in Android jellyBean

Tags: android, sms, messaging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to send Text messages to different contacts in a bulk. The contacts are several hundred and i'm reading them from a text file. Now when my app tries to send messages , A Dialog Appears telling

> App is sending too much messages => Allow , Deny

I've studied several forums that it's a restriction introduced in JellyBean to prevent malicious activity and it can't be undone without rooting your device and running some weird scripts. Is there a fix to this problem? if there isn't any fix , then can we Programatically click Allow button on that message dialog within our app? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a fix to this problem?

Send fewer messages.

Or, send the messages at a slower rate.

Or, use some sort of online SMS gateway to send the messages, perhaps through a serve of yours, rather than sending them through Android's `SmsManager`. You can find some of these by searching for `online sms gateway` on your favorite search engine.

> can we Programatically click Allow button on that message dialog within our app?

No. The point behind the block is so that the *user* gets a vote as to whether your app can spend quite so much money (or SMS allotment from a post-paid plan) on the user's behalf. Bulk SMS is not designed to be done from Android, but rather from an online SMS gateway.

Comment: So can we prompt user for HIS vote if he want to allow our app spend that much money or send sms in bulk? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Ahmed: Android is already doing that, in the form of this dialog.

Comment: it should ask only once , the dialog keeps appearing and we've to keep taping Allow button :/

Comment: @Ahmed: I would consider that to be a very strong hint that Google does not want Android to be used for bulk SMS delivery.

Comment: we can do this in earliers versions on android though , like ICS and i read android developers forum , almost everyone was complaining :/